# debug draw Box2D very large compared to Testbed app

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, box2d

I'm trying to set up Box2D in my own game. I've currently got some code working and I added a DebugDraw class to my game which draws the polygons created by Box2D.

Now, if I compare this with the code from the Testbed app (I copied some code to recreate the OneSidedPlatform test) it shows up much bigger in my game then in the original app.

I guess this has something to do with OpenGL/SDL itself so here is some code:

This sets up OpenGL in my game:

```
// START SDL
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
{
    logSDLError(std::cout, "SDL_Init");
    return 1;
}

// SETUP OPENGL SETTINGS (THEY CAN BE SET WITHOUT ACTUALLY BEING USED)
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

// CREATE A WINDOW
m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL/OpenGL Game Client - With Networking Library", 100, 100, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
if (m_pWindow == nullptr)
{
    logSDLError(std::cout, "CreateWindow");
    return 2;
}

m_GlContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_pWindow);
if( m_GlContext == NULL )
{
    printf( "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
}
else
{
    //INITIALIZE GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
    GLenum glewError = glewInit();
    if( glewError != GLEW_OK )
    {
        printf( "Error initializing GLEW! %s\n", glewGetErrorString( glewError ) );
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

// CREATE A RENDERER TO DRAW THE WINDOW TO
m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
if (m_pRenderer == nullptr)
{
    logSDLError(std::cout, "CreateRenderer");
    return 3;
}
```

This is the creation of the Box2D objects (copy from original test app):

```
// Ground
{
    b2BodyDef bd;
    b2Body* ground = Engine::GetInstance()->GetPhysicsWorld()->CreateBody(&bd);

    b2EdgeShape shape;
    shape.Set(b2Vec2(-20.0f, 0.0f), b2Vec2(20.0f, 0.0f));
    ground->CreateFixture(&shape, 0.0f);
}

// Platform
{
    b2BodyDef bd;
    bd.position.Set(0.0f, 10.0f);
    b2Body* body = Engine::GetInstance()->GetPhysicsWorld()->CreateBody(&bd);

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(3.0f, 0.5f);
    m_platform = body->CreateFixture(&shape, 0.0f);

    m_bottom = 10.0f - 0.5f;
    m_top = 10.0f + 0.5f;
}

// Actor
{
    b2BodyDef bd;
    bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bd.position.Set(0.0f, 12.0f);
    b2Body* body = Engine::GetInstance()->GetPhysicsWorld()->CreateBody(&bd);

    m_radius = 0.5f;
    b2CircleShape shape;
    shape.m_radius = m_radius;
    m_character = body->CreateFixture(&shape, 20.0f);

    body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0.0f, -50.0f));

    m_state = e_unknown;
}

// Set debug
Engine::GetInstance()->GetPhysicsWorld()->SetDebugDraw(&m_debugDraw);
m_debugDraw.SetFlags(b2Draw::e_shapeBit);
```

I have no idea where I have to look to change the view of my game or the scale of Box2D. I also compared my OpenGL code to the one from the Testbed app and I can't find any real difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this method in Main.cpp from TestBed app:

```
static void Resize(int32 w, int32 h)
{
    ...
    // those are the lines you may consider incorporating into your code:

    b2Vec2 lower = settings.viewCenter - extents;
    b2Vec2 upper = settings.viewCenter + extents;

    // L/R/B/T
    gluOrtho2D(lower.x, upper.x, lower.y, upper.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) that did indeed solve it! I really have to look into how to use matrices in games...